# How to express adj(A) in terms of A if A is singular?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find out how to 'simplify' adj(AB) and adj(adj(A)) when A is singular? I have a hint to consider $A+\lambda I$. I tried calculating the adjugate of $A+\lambda I$ but this doesn't seem to simplify to anything nice enough to be of use.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is that for every value of $\lambda$ except for the eigenvalues of $-A$, $A + \lambda I$ is *invertible*.  For any invertible matrix $A$, we have
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\adj}{adj}
\adj(A) = \det(A)A^{-1}
$$
And, by the continuity of the map $A \mapsto \adj(A)$, we have
$$
A = \lim_{\lambda \to 0} \adj(A + \lambda I)
$$
What this means for us is that any results we find that work for invertible matrices can be quickly extended to the non-invertible cases via this limiting process.

These questions are surprisingly easy if we consider the invertible case.  In particular, if $A$ and $B$ are invertible, we have
$$
\adj(AB) = \det(AB)(AB)^{-1} = [\det(B)B^{-1}] [\det(A)A^{-1}] = 
\adj(B)\adj(A)
$$
If $A$ is invertible, we have
$$
\adj(\adj(A)) = \det(\adj(A))\adj(A)^{-1} = \\
\det(\det(A)A^{-1})[\det(A)A^{-1}]^{-1} = \\
[\det(A)]^n \det[A^{-1}][\det(A)]^{-1} A = \\
[\det(A)]^{n-2} A
$$
These formulas also hold when $A$ is singular.

---

So, for example, let's *prove* that the first formula holds for singular $A$.  We note that for any sufficiently small $\lambda$, we have
$$
\adj([A + \lambda I]B) = \adj(B) \adj(A + \lambda I)
$$
By the continuity of $\adj$, we have
$$
\adj(AB) = 
 \adj(\lim_{\lambda \to 0}[A + \lambda I]B) = 
\lim_{\lambda \to 0} \adj([A + \lambda I]B) =\\
\lim_{\lambda \to 0} \adj(B) \adj(A + \lambda I) =
\adj(B)\adj(\lim_{\lambda \to 0}[A + \lambda I]) = \\
\adj(B)\adj(A)
$$

Comment: This makes sense, except how to can we be sure $A+\lambda I$ is invertible?

Comment: @Guest195 if $\lambda$ is non-zero and is not an eigenvalue of $-A$, then $A + \lambda I$ must be invertible.  At the very least, realize that most values of $\lambda$ are not eigenvalues of $-A$.